# Laravel how to set or define number of workers?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

In laravel you can start a queue listener with:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

But how many workers (threads, processes) will be used to process the queue?
Is there any way to define the number of workers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/queues#supervisor-configuration

You generate a config file where you define the number of workers.

```
numprocs=10
```

Comment: thank you! that's the answer. I tought Laravel provided a method builtin to run multiple worker, but in this case either you run multiple times that command or you use supervisord.

Answer (score 5):

By running `php artisan queue:listen` only one process will be run and fetches the jobs from the queue. So the jobs will be fetched and processed one by one.

If you want to have more than one thread to process the queue jobs you need to run the listener many times in different consoles. But instead of running them manually you can use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to manage your threads then you will be able to configure the number of thread by setting `numprocs` parameter in Supervisor [configuration setting](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration)